# Bash - enable execution only if script is run from a specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix, shell-script

I need to write a shell script that can only be executed if it is run from the home directory of the currently signed-in user, and I have no idea how to check that from the script itself. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at variable `$0` in your script..

Comment: `if [ $PWD != $HOME ]; then exit; fi`

Comment: @AFH you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the environment variables PWD and HOME: `$PWD` is the current working directory, while `$HOME` is the current user's home directory. You can precede the executable statements in your script by:

```
if [ "$PWD" != "$HOME" ]; then exit; fi
```

You can optionally add an error code to the `exit` command, in case the calling shell wants to check the success or failure of the script.

Another useful variable is OLDPWD: `$OLDPWD` is the previous directory before the last directory change. You can use this to make the script run from anywhere, by surrounding the script with:

```
cd "$HOME"
. . . . . .
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

This presupposes that there are no other directory changes in the script; if not, use `INITPWD="$PWD"` first and return to `$INITPWD`. In point of fact, in most circumstances the script will run in a subshell, so the change back to the original directory will be unnecessary, since the initial `cd` will not affect the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

may be use at the beginning of script:
LOCATION=/path/to/script
if [ "PWD" != "$LOCATION" ];
then cd $LOCATION